# AJAX loading of a view on click of a button?

Tags: views, javascript, ajax

I want to switch between two methods of sorting and displaying items in Views by toggling a button. My exposed filters are in the URL so I want to include the query in the path in order to keep the exposed filter results. Both displays of the view have "use ajax" set to "yes".

My link is :

```
$link_path = ($display_data->display_options['path'] . '/nojs');
$query = drupal_get_query_parameters();
$toggle_link = l($toggle_icon, $link_path, array('html' => true, 'query' => $query, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax'))));
```

Which outputs something like:

```
<a href="href="/my_view_page_1/nojs?terms=test&param1[0]=123">[omitted SVG path for brevity]</a>
```

In a js file in my theme, I have:

```
    /**
     * Toggle button and ajax views
     */
    var viewId = settings.mytheme_toggle_view.view;
    var viewDisplayId = settings.mytheme_toggle_view.current_display;
    var viewOtherDisplayId = settings.mytheme_toggle_view.other_display;
    $.ajax({
        url: settings.basePath + 'views/ajax/' + settings.mytheme_toggle_view.query,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          view_name: viewId,
          view_display_id: viewOtherDisplayId,
          view_args: {}, // your views arguments
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var newView = ($(response[1].data));
            $(".view-display-id-" + viewDisplayId).replaceWith($(newView));
        }
    });
    /* End views ajax stuff. */
```

What happens now:

1. I go to my view and select my exposed filters and hit "apply"
2. I arrive at my view's default display page
3. Before I can click anything, AJAX fires and replaces the view content with the alternative view content.
4. If I click the toggle, it is a link (with full page reload, not AJAX) to the default display page again.
5. Step 3 repeats.

What I want is for the view to

1. Not change on pageload, but wait until the toggle button is clicked
2. Be able to be toggled back and forth rather than only toggling once and then becoming a regular, page-reloading link.
3. Preserve the exposed filters
4. Have the pager still work (currently is a link to some JSON output of the settings object).

Answer (score 0):

[Views Modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_modes)

> A Drupal Views display plugin which provides alternate display modes
>   that can be switched to for a single View. This allows exposed filter
>   parameters or contextual filters to be kept active while switching
>   display mode.

Sounds like this module does what you're trying to do. There's only a dev version, but might be worth a look.